# Call interface method using reference of class

Tags: c#, .net, interface

I want to call an interface method using the reference of a class which implements that interface. I am using reflection for that but my code is not working and I am getting null object reference exception. The code is give below:

```
interface IntA
{
    void MethodFirst();
}

interface IntB
{
    void MethodFirst();
}

class ClassA : IntA, IntB
{
    public void MethodFirst()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("this.ClassA.MethodFirst");
    }
    void IntA.MethodFirst()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("IntA.ClassA.MethodFirst");
    }
    void IntB.MethodFirst()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("IntB.ClassA.MethodFirst");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        Type t = Type.GetType("ClassA");
            t.GetMethod("MethodFirst").Invoke(Activator.CreateInstance(t,null), null);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }        
}
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong over here.

Comment: simply cast your class to interface and call your method. you don't need reflection

Comment: Thanks M. kazem Akhgary. It was an interview question to call it using reflection.

Comment: using reflection is something at expert level and you only use it when you really need it. that's very rare. if you are good programmer you never need reflection ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to try creating instance of your class using the full namespace of that class. for example,

```
Type t = Type.GetType("ConsoleApplication1.ClassA");
```

In case, if you want to call a method from a particular interface -

```
Type t = Type.GetType("ConsoleApplication1.ClassA");
t.GetInterface("ConsoleApplication1.IntB").GetMethod("MethodFirst").Invoke(Activator.CreateInstance(t, null), null);
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. But now I want to call IntB.MethodFirst. How can I call it?

Answer (score 0):

```
        IntA classA = new ClassA();
        classA.MethodFirst();
        Console.ReadLine();
```